# Google Calendar API: Possible to get reminders due in a certain period?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

I wonder if its possible to get reminders due in a certain period of time. I am working on a Calendar app. I was thinking of using Google Calendar as a "backend/calendar storage engine". Since implementing a calendar backend seems hard. The recurrences and reminders part. The challenge that I have now is, I want to send push notifications for reminders. So was wondering if there is a way to query for reminders due the next hour for example.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Reminders* are alarms triggered at a specified time before an event starts

However, the [delivery mechanisms](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/reminders#delivery_mechanisms) only available by Google API are

> *Pop-up*. These are supported on mobile platforms and on web clients.
>
> *Email* sent by the server.
>
> *SMS*. These are only available for Google Apps for Work, Education, and Government customers.

Push Notification is a bit different, as you're required to have a GCM Connection Server with additional configurations in the developer console.

Comment: Is this push notification from my app? I want to send push notifications from my app not Google

Comment: There are no push notification available based on the delivery mechanisms for the Calendar API. If you want to have push notifications, you can check out their [Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) documentation. From there, you can implement a way for it to connect to the Calendar and notify the necessary devices/clients.

Comment: I think the unsolved problem I have now is how to schedule notifications efficiently. I will need to know which reminders are due in a specified time range, then send a push.